# OUTPUT clause with INSERT

Tags: sql-server

I have a vacation request program that will ultimately save the vacation request data to the DB and then send an email to the users supervisor.

I use the following query to INSERT a row into the DB.

```
    String strSQLNew = "INSERT INTO tblWP_TS_VacRequest (VacReqID, ReqStatus, ApproveDate, SubmitDate, CreateDate, VacNotes, HRVacNotes) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.VacReqID 
    VALUES(NEWID(), '" + sReqStatus + "', NULL, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), '" + sVacNotes + "', '" + sHRVacNotes + "'); ";

    sVacReqID = Cm.ex(Cm.pld, strSQLNew, "5000", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, true);
```

Cm.ex is a routine we use thoughout our code to access the DB.

I use `OUTPUT Inserted.VacReqID` because I need the newly created `VacReqID` for the next step in my program. As soon as the data is inserted, I want to display the data to the user. I use a `SELECT` statement `WHERE VacReqID =` this new ID. In the table I have a column called `VacReqNum`. This is a sequential number that is displayed to the user for reference. This column has the following properties: IsIdentity, Identity Increment = 1, Identity Seed = 1.

Most times everything works fine. The problem comes in on the rare occasion when two people, User A and User B, happen to use the program at the same time and hit SUBMIT at the same time.

User A will receive an email with her name and correct `VacReqNum` but with User B's requested days off.

User B will receive an email with all correct data.

When I look at `tblWP_TS_VacRequest` I see the inserted row for User B but nothing for User A. I am not understanding how this happens. I know that User A's data is inserted because of the `VacReqNum` that is on the email. To confirm this User B's `VacReqNum` is 1 more than User A. This is the first time that I have used OUTPUT and a column that is automatically incremented at one time. Is there something wrong with my INSERT/OUTPUT query?

I don't access the DB when I create the email. After the data is inserted I get the data and put in an array using the VacReqID. I use the array to populate the body of the email. This is the query I use to get the data to fill the array.

```
    SELECT VacReqNum, CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ReqDay, 101) AS ReqDate, CAST(ReqHours AS decimal(4,1)) AS ReqHours, VacReqDay.VacReqID, VacReqDayID 
    FROM tblWP_TS_VacRequestDay VacReqDay 
    JOIN tblWP_TS_VacRequest VacReq ON VacReq.VacReqID = VacReqDay.VacReqID 
    WHERE VacReqDay.VacReqID = sVacReqID 
    ORDER BY CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ReqDay, 101)
```

Comment: It seems you are speaking of identity values, and yet your output clause is actually capturing the NEWID() value so this doesn't seem to fit between what you say you are doing and what your code is doing. In general, using a [Sequence](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-sequence/) is probably a good idea here.

Comment: Where does this email that you talk about come from? This feels like the result and your assumed cause are not related. The above has nothing to do with sending emails.

Comment: I need the VacReqID, which is the NEWID(),  for other tables but I want the VacReqNum to display to the user. The email is created later in the code.

Comment: What are you doing with the value of OUTPUT Inserted.VacReqID? If you need to know that uniqueidentifier was inserted, I recommend giving it one as a variable (declare, set, if you can) instead of generating it in the Values and asking for it through OUTPUT.

Comment: The data is INSERTED, then the VacReqID is used to gather all the data for this request. Then the code is called to create the email.

Comment: HOW are you capturing the GUID that is generated? That `output Inserted.VacReqID` will "select" it like a select statement. Are you setting it to a variable? Putting it in a table? How are you capturing it?

Comment: @BrianStork - yes, I am setting it to a variable

Comment: Could you show that in your code example? Because your code example just selects it.

Comment: *"The email is created later in the code. "* you might need to include some of that relevant code.

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put code like that in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm...I don't know how well this can be investigate without knowing more about how Cm.ex() works ... what it returns, how it executes, if there is adequate transaction handling or not ... lots of questions I guess. It is possibly less clear now what the output clause is doing since it's getting washed through another function.

Comment: @topsail - The VacReqNum is automatically created when the row is INSERTED, I don't add that number. I get the VacReqNum using a SELECT statement with the VacRecID. It seems it would have to of been saved at one point to get it and for that number to be incremented for the next Vacation Request.

Comment: Yes, I know that seems like it should work. Can you clarify here: *When I look at tblWP_TS_VacRequest I see the inserted row for User B but nothing for User A. I am not understanding how this happens. I know that User A's data is inserted because of the VacReqNum that is on the email. To confirm this User B's VacReqNum is 1 more than User A.* When you say you see nothing for User A - that sounds like the insert failed. But then immediately in the next line you say that User A has a VacReqNum (one less than User B) and that sounds like the insert did not fail...

Comment: @topsail - On the email the VacReqNum for User A shows 865. User B shows 866. I use SELECT * FROM tblWP_TS_VacRequest ORDER BY VacReqNum desc. VacReqNum 866 is there, 865 is missing like it was never saved. But if the email shows 865 and that number is only created when data is inserted into the table, how can it not be there? I only get this number when I use a SELECT statement to populate the array.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking this was the case. A failed insertion can "use up" an auto incremented identity value. It goes something like this - server "gives" out the new id for the inserted row, the row is NOT inserted (it fails for some reason - perhaps rolled back or whatever), but the identity value is now discarded. The next insertion get the next value and there is a gap in your ids now. So perhaps the code is not detecting failed insertions and likewise not letting you know about them correctly. This is a common pitfall in sql development - handling sql errors is usually poor or non-existent.

Comment: @topsail - The routine we use to access the DB doesn't have a great error handling so what you say makes sense.  But how can I get that 'used up' number when I do a SELECT statement?

Comment: *"Cm.ex is a routine we use thoughout our code to access the DB."* Mistake #1: a generic unparameterized function that accesses the database. You should instead tailor a function for that piece of SQL, with the correct parameters. Do **not** inject data into your queries. You have a **major** SQL injection vulnerability going on here, which might be the root of your issues.

Comment: Well the "used up number" is useless - unless it was used as the id for a successful insertion, it just represents a record that doesn't exist. It is hard to say though - you probably need some expert eyes on this, first hand. Otherwise, to really dig into this you may need to detail the process from start to finish with relevant examples of the code involved (possibly - from the db side as well as the application side). I can only say that generally you want to get back a reliable indication from the database whether or not the operation succeeded (and, in this case, some way to ID it too).